# How to send a JSON request with params in middle of URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, object-literal

I have been trying to create a node.js json request object. And i need to pass a parameter in middle of url path. I am giving the below however it is not working.. COuld you please help ?

```
var alertModel = {
                method:'GET',
                pathparam:{accountNum: '21703774771466'},
                path:"/v1/note/sen/${accountNum}/notes",
                qs:{

                    category:'NOTES'
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with double quotes. Instead use backticks:

```
path: `/v1/note/sen/${accountNum}/notes`,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backquote:

```
let accountNum=21703774771466;
var alertModel = {
    method:'GET',
    path:`/v1/note/sen/${accountNum}/notes`,
    qs:{

        category:'NOTES'
    }
}
```

work with node.js >= 4.x.x